# Which machine is more reliable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Consider two discrete random variables indicating the length of a product produced by two machines (machine A and machine B). The normal length should be $450$ mm, but the length of the product varies for each machine with the following probabilities.

[image]

> My question is which machine is more reliable?

I have calculated the expected value of the product length for each machine, and both are equal to $450$ mm.

Since the expected value equals the the normal length, do we have to check the probability $\Pr(X=450)$ at each machine?

Comment: A good way to gauge the reliability would be to compute the variance of $X$. A lower value of the variance indicates that the machine is more reliable.

Comment: Ah ok! For the machine A we have the following: The formula is \begin{equation*}\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\left (\mathbb{E}[X]\right )^2\end{equation*} \begin{align*}E&(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^2\cdot P(X=x_i)\\ & =x_1^2\cdot P(X=x_1)+x_2^2\cdot P(X=x_2)+x_3^2\cdot P(X=x_3)+x_4^2\cdot P(X=x_4)+x_5^2\cdot P(X=x_5)\\ & =440^2\cdot P(X=440)+445^2\cdot P(X=445)+450^2\cdot P(X=450)+455^2\cdot P(X=455)+460^2\cdot P(X=460)\\ & =193600\cdot P(X=440)+198025\cdot P(X=445)+202500\cdot P(X=450)+207025\cdot P(X=455)+211600\cdot P(X=460)\\ & =4840+39605+111375+41405+5290\\ & =202515 \end{align*} @MathLover

Comment: So \begin{equation*}\text{Var}_A(X)=202515-450^2=202515-202500=15\end{equation*} right?  @MathLover

Comment: Do you mean that we cannot check it with the variance? @angryavian

Comment: @angryavian It would be reliable, but will have a bias. In the given problem, both machines depict no bias in terms of the product length.

Comment: @MaryStar I haven't checked the calculations. In this case, it is better to use $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2]$ as you do not have to deal with large numbers. In any case, machine B should have lower variance.

Comment: I found that the variance for the machine B is 16,25. Therefore machine A is more reliable, right? @MathLover

Comment: it all depends on the definition of reliability. According to estimation theory terminology it is the MSE and for unbiased estimators, the one with the lowest variance is the reliable one. However, it depends on the application as well. For example if we produce a product and if its legth is less or more than exactly 450mm, we throw it away, then the reliable one has the largest $P(X=450)$.

Comment: Does this mean that in this case since $P(X=450)$ is bigger for the machine B, the variance of B should be smaller than that of A ? @SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: @MaryStar I think the variance of $B$ should be smaller than that of $A$. That's why I was suggesting you to use $E[(X-E[X])^2]$ to compute the variances.

Comment: Shuld it be like that because the probability $P(X=450)$ at B is bigger than at A? @MathLover

Comment: No. There is no correlation between both. I havent calculated the varianace of A and B. I say that the anwer to this question depends on the definition of reliability and such a definition is not given in the question so it is a bit vague.

Comment: Ah ok. Unfortnunately it is not given exaclty what it is meant about reliability. (The machines produce belts.) @SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: it is the same with your formulation of variance. $var=m_2-{m_1}^2$

Comment: I found again the same result: $$A: (440-450)^2\cdot 0.025+(445-450)^2\cdot 0.2+(450-450)^2\cdot 0.55+(455-450)^2\cdot 0.2+(460-450)^2\cdot 0.025=15$$ 

$$B: (440-450)^2\cdot 0.05+(445-450)^2\cdot 0.15+(450-450)^2\cdot 0.575+(455-450)^2\cdot 0.2+(460-450)^2\cdot 0.025=16,25$$ @MathLover Have I done something wrong?

Comment: So you mean as I did in my previous comment, or not? We get that the variance of A is smaller than that of B. Does this mean that A is more reliable? @SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: the formulation seems correct. if your calculations are also correct then indeed the variance of A is lower. This makes A more consistent than B. As I told you I cannot tell you anything if it is also reliable or not. The question is problematic. Ask to the person who asked you this question: what do you mean by reliability. 

I guess he/she means variance but once again, it could well be $P(X=450)$ as well...

Comment: So, if we consider the variance the more reliable machine is A and if we consider $P(X=450)$ the more reliable machine is B, right? @SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: yes. think like this. you wanna produce something and throw away if it is not perfect. If you produce 100 belts lets say, then, on average you will get $55$ of them correct with A but $\approx 58$ of them correct with B. So you will choose $B$. On the other hand, if you wont throw away the incorrect ones but it all depends on the daviation from the true value which is $450$, the you will choose $A$. Why? because A gives you on average closer results to the true value $450$ compared to $B$. One can have kind of deviation $15$ and the other $16.5$. Definitely, you would want the one with $15$.

Comment: just out of curiosity. where was this question asked? is this a high school question in Germany?

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!! :-) @SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: I am trying to solve by myself some exercises. I found this one online.

Comment: Alright, good luck.